# Laravel Eloquent relationship for user to friends

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5.4, eloquent

I am confused with eloquent relationships. I have two tables:

```
USERS:
id, name, pwd, etc...

FRIENDS:
id, user_id, friend_id
```

For the FRIENDS table, I have two foreign keys:

```
$t->foreign('user_id')
  ->references('id')
  ->on('users');

$t->foreign('friend_id')
  ->references('id')
  ->on('users');
```

In each class I have the following relationships:

USER class:

```
/**
 * A user can have many friends
 */
public function friends()
{
    return $this->hasMany(User::class, 'friend_id', 'id');
}
```

FRIEND class:

```
/**
 * A friend can belong to a user
 */
public function friend()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'id', 'user_id');
}

/**
 * A user friends are connected to
 */
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'id', 'friend_id');
}
```

I want to end up with

```
Auth::user()->friends()->get();
```

Should the relationship be a `hasManyThrough()`? How do I implement this when the USERS table is self referenced via the FRIENDS table?

Comment: first of all why do you have a friend_id in the friend table

Comment: @Didi, its for pivot. i bet he only need to remove the `id` in the pivot table. @TheRealPapa, i don't think you will need `hasManyThrough()` since this one is direct many-to-many relationship.

Comment: Yeah, you dont need the hasManyThrough().

Answer (score 5, accepted):

migration:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('friend_user', function(Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('friend_id')->unsigned()->index();
        $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned()->index();
        $table->foreign('friend_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
    });
}
```

User model:

```
public function friends()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'friend_user', 'user_id', 'friend_id');
}
```

*UPDATE*

Get all friends:

```
Auth::user()->friends (or Auth::user()->friends()->get())
```

Add friends:

```
Auth::user()->friends()->attach([2,3,4]); // Add user_id 2, 3 and 4
```

Remove friends:

```
Auth::user()->friends()->detach([2]); // Remove user_id = 2
```

Sync friends:

```
Auth::user()->friends()->sync([7]); // Remove old and add user_id = 7
```

Comment: No friend class needed

Comment: I think I missed something in your answer: if it is a many-to-many relationship, then there is a `users` table, a `friends` table and the pivot table `friend_user`… but what does contain the `friends` table if the relationships are stored within the pivot table?

Comment: this will fetch only tables where the Auth::user()->id is equal to  'user_id' and not 'followed_id'

Answer (score 0):

There is no need `friends` table, since there are imaginary 2 table `users` and again `users` table, that is why you dont need `friends` table