# Elegant way to create M:N relationships between the same models in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, relationship, laravel-relations

I am trying to define a model relationship that I believe is extremely ordinary, but I just could not find any elegant way to do it in Laravel. I'm talking about a *same-model m:n relationship*. Let's say you want to define a *friends* relationship:

```php
class User extends Model
{
    public function friends(): BelongsToMany
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'friends');
    }
}
```

Well, this won't work both ways, because you might probably expect a table similar to this:

```
friends:
 - (int) id
 - (int) first_user_id
 - (int) second_user_id
 - (bool) is_accepted (default 0)
```

And now, in the model, you would have been supposed to define the foreign key names. Which one is foreign? The typical use case is that one user will send a request to another, and then the other one will accept/reject it. But you will have to assign the users to that M:N relationship, you will have to do some validation (e.g., aren't they friends already?), you will have to check if the other user didn't already send a request (which is pending) to the first one and so on. However, I am trying to avoid something like the following.

```php
class User extends Model
{
    public function myFriends(): BelongsToMany
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'friends', 'first_user_id', 'second_user_id');
    }

    public function friendOf(): BelongsToMany
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'friends', 'second_user_id', 'first_user_id');
    }
}
```

I am trying to think of a data structure that would allow this to happen as a classic relationship, but I could not quite get to it. Any ideas? Is it even possible while keeping the traditional Eloquent-relationship methods?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45450045/laravel-eloquent-relationship-for-user-to-friends/45450547

Comment: @HashtagForgotName That won't work in both directions. If you will do `$me->frineds()`, you will only get friends, where your `id` is in the `user_id` column. Not those, where you are in the `friend_id` column.

Comment: I can see but i assume that u want to accomplish that user can create friends in your code // application that that's the way how u can implements it and u can still add `(bool) is_accepted (default 0)` the friends table if u still want to make that accept and deny method

Comment: "I am trying to avoid something like this" why? That's how it's done.

Comment: seconded, a pivot is the way forward here as @HashtagForgotName has linked.

Comment: @miken32 Because every work with *friends* will basically be doubled. Saving, retrieving, modifying, verifying,... I can make some helping methods for the basic operations, but I was trying to keep up with the Eloquent conventions.

Answer (score -1):

You can define a new class and table "frienduser" which has three inputs

'user_1','user-2','is_accepted'

user_1 is sender

user_2 for receiver

Friends table contains duplicate data.

id,user_id,friend_id,friend_user_id

1,1,2,1

2,2,1,1

```
class FriendUser extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'friend_user';

    use HasFactory;
  
}
```

Friend class

```
class Friend extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    public function friend_info()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class,'friend_id');
    }
      public function friend_user()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Models\FriendUser', 'id','friend_user_id')->first();

    }
}
```

Controller

```
$frienduser= Auth::user()->friends()->where('friend_id','=','2')->first()->frienduser();
 $frienduser->isaccepted=1;
 $frienduser->save();
```